# background-size: cover doesn't work for height

Tags: css

I have to make a wallpaper and stretch it to the screen,
the CSS3 cover doesn't really help VERTICALLY

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

I saw some post but they didn't work with me.

This is my code :

```
background-image: url('/wallpapers/img.jpg');
background-repeat:  no-repeat;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

Any Idea please ?

Comment: We'd need the HTML...what element are you applying this CSS to?

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle.net?

Comment: you are loading the image in wrong manner it should be like `background-image: url('/wallpapers/img.jpg');`

Comment: @Amitsingh no it's url('/wallpapers/img.jpg') you are adding some extra ticks

Comment: @vlrprbttst i think we should follow the rules of giving the correct path to load the image. it should be inside the quotation

Answer (score 1):

you have some syntax errors, the right code is

```
body {
    background-image: url("/wallpapers/img.jpg");
    background-size: cover;}
```

Comment: ah ok yeah, i see you corrected it. apply the background to the body and you are all set. did it work?

Comment: Yeah, it is in the body tag already, my problem was in  HTML height. thx anyway